# MSI pe62-8rc overheating in ubuntu 18.04 but not in windows

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, overheating, msi

I am quite new to Ubuntu and I have installed Ubuntu alongside Win 10. The problem is that when I am surfing by chrome in Ubuntu, the fans getting run faster especially the **right** fan. They work great and the temp is going down after a while (I had monitored temp using lm-sensors), but my laptop (**MSI pe62-8rc**) is not overheating this much in Win 10. 
I think there is a problem with graphics card drive since I had problem in installing that (First time I boot Ubuntu 18.04, I got black screen by installing one version of nvidia that I cannot remember now).

Now in Software and Updates:
Using Nvidia driver metapackage from **nvidia-driver-440**

I have tried updating ubuntu and also driver-autoinsitall. I have also tried upgrating Ubuntu. 
system info: 
Graphics: GeForce® GTX 1050 with 4GB GDDR5
CPU: CoffeeLake Core i7-8750H ~ 4.1GHz 9MB
Memory: 8GB DDR4-2666MHz
Storage Disk: 1TB HDD+128GB SSD (Ubuntu and win 10 in ssd)